# Why this inverter is used in the PWM circuit?

Tags: pwm, dc-dc-converter, boost

The circuit below is a programmable duty cycle modulator for boost converter in a paper. As from the picture, there are two signals *CLK/64* and *CLK/64SHIFTED*. Could you explain why the signal *CLK/64* is inverted by the inverter before connecting to the input of NAND gate?
Thank you.

[image]

I have just drawn the output of NAND gate in two cases. The first one with the inverter is Q1 and the second case Q2 is without the inverter.
As you can see the two waveform are similar in T, Ton, Toff. So I am wondering what is the function of this inverter.

[image: Output of NAND gate in two cases]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that the delay line has a minimum delay equal to that of an inverter. This means that if the minimum delay time is selected, the inputs at the NAND gate will be the inverse of each other and therefore duty cycle on the output will be zero. This could allow the process to shut-down the boost converter for indefinite periods. This might be akin to cycle skipping, a technique used in many switching regulators.

Comment: Thank you. That makes some sense! However, I don't understand why should we shut-down the boost converter in this case. Shouldn't we keep the duty cycle constant when no delay?

Comment: @user3126592 with changing load conditions on the output, it is very likely that a dwell period with no energy being dumped to the output is the only way to keep a sudden load removal from causing the output voltage to sky rocket.

Comment: Could you explain more? Do you mean that there is no load at output?

Comment: Anyone designing a boost converter will design it to work with a large variation in load range. That load range could include total removal of the load. When that happens you don't want to be dumping energy into the boost converters output because the output voltage will rise linearly as it charges up the output capacitor with no load present to discharge it.

Answer (score 2):

Let's call the input of the delay line D. The inputs of the NAND A (upper one) and B (lower one). The output of the NAND is called Q.

Start: D=1, A=1, B=0, Q=1

Then we change: D->0 then B->1 and therefore Q->0
After D propagates through the delay line: B->0 and therefore Q->1.

So we get a short zero pulse, having the length of the delay given by the delay line.

It's basically this circuit, the important thing is the *delay*:
[image]

Comment: Thank you. I tried to draw the output of NAND gate in two cases one with the NOT gate and one without it. The results are the same waveform shape and duty cycle in both cases. That is a bit confusing.

Comment: See my update to the answer.

Comment: Well, I understand how the short pulse is created. However, for the NAND gate from the picture above, if you omit the NOT gate at one input of the NAND gate, the result is still the same. So I don't understand why it it put there.

Comment: No, the logic function is very different with and without the inverter. With the inverter, it functions as an edge detector. The pulse width is independent of the period. Without the inverter, the pulse is just a slightly shortened version of the clock signal.

Comment: Plese see my update above. The cases are same in terms of T, Ton, Toff.

Comment: As written above, the delay is of importance. The use of the inverter gives a different phase relationship. So it depends on the application. Maybe you can provide a reference to the paper.

Comment: This is the paper. If you can't access it, I will send you a copy.
http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/login.jsp?tp=&arnumber=7184928&url=http%3A%2F%2Fieeexplore.ieee.org%2Fxpls%2Fabs_all.jsp%3Farnumber%3D7184928

Comment: I had a quick look at the paper. The signal is used to drive boost converter. So the duration of the zero phase determines the output voltage. Therefore the polarity makes sense. As always this could be done differently, i.e. without an inverter. But the delay would still be needed and then you would have needed an inverter somewhere else.

Comment: Hi, I don't see the different between with and without the inverter. If you see the output of NAND gate Q1 and Q2 for two cases with and without the inverter, you will see that they are exactly the same in terms of T, Ton, Toff. So could you explain why inverter is used here?

Comment: No, the phase is different and the duty cycle, too.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36785/discussion-between-user3126592-and-mario).

Comment: Well, as from the picture above, phase is different but duty cycle is exactly the same.

Comment: The signal is the inverse. So the duty cycle is one minus the first DC. There is a difference between say 10% or 1-10%=90%.

Comment: Well, I am not sure if you can see two signals Q1 and Q2 posted in my first post. Both signal have duty cycle 75%. Ton = 3Toff.

Comment: I upload the image again here. Could you explain based on the picture: http://i.imgur.com/Mrru7e7.jpg

Comment: @Mario: How would you explain this?

Comment: You are right. In this case we have the some DC. However, the phase is different.